# How to reduce the size of Bert model(checkpoint/model_state.bin) using pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, data-science, bert-language-model

I used `torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic` to reduce the model size but it is reducing my prediction Accuracy score.

I'm using that model file inside the Flask and doing some real time predictions, Due to the large size i'm facing issues while predicting. So could anyone please help me on reducing the bert model size using pytorch and guide me on who to do the real time predictions.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic.html#torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic) is the doc of `torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic` where `dtype` is set to `torch.qint8`.

so if you dont want your accuracy to drastically decrease use the below syntax

`torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic(model, qconfig_spec=None, dtype=torch.float16)`

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ya i tried it but i want to know any other methods for achieving it other than `torch.quantization.quantize_dynamic`

Comment: u should definitely try quantization aware training , if u want more accurate `int8` models